# Perl equivalent idiom for Python's warnings module

Tags: python, perl, warnings

I need to port some code from Python to Perl. The Python code makes simple use of the [warnings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) module, e.g.

```
warnings.warn("Hey I'm a warning.")
```

I've been googling around quite a bit but it's unclear to me what the equivalent Perl idiom might be. How would a Perl programmer handle this?

Comment: [Useful information about Perl Carp module](https://metacpan.org/module/Carp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To write a message to `STDERR`, simply use the built-in [`warn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) function.

```
warn "Hey I'm a warning.";
```

But you should *also* use Perl's [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) module, as well as [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) because they turn on all kinds of useful compiler warnings and error checking for you.

Therefore, begin all your programs with

```
use strict;
use warnings;

warn "Hey I'm a warning.";
```

(You don't need the `warnings` module to use the `warn` function, though.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want something more in-depth than the simple `warn` function, you can use the `Carp` module. One of the particularly nice things about it is that it will let you print stacktraces with either warnings or errors. Full documentation available [on the Perl site](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html).